# ng-selected attribute is not working on ion-select

Tags: android, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

Good Day Everyone!

**PROBLEM: Failed to display a selected option from a dynamic ion-select**

**DESCRIPTION:**

I have two ion-select (dropdown), one for the **city** field and one for the **barangay** field. The **barangay** field displays dynamic values based on the selected **city**. This works properly but when I try to display a selected value, it doesn't work.

**HTML**

```
                  <!-- City -->
                  <ion-item class="form-field">
                    <ion-label stacked>City</ion-label>
                    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="city" (ionChange)="getBarangay('house')">
                      <ion-option value="Caloocan (NORTH) City" ng-selected="city == 'Caloocan (NORTH) City'">Caloocan City</ion-option>
                      <ion-option value="Caloocan (SOUTH) City" ng-selected="city == 'Caloocan (SOUTH) City'">Caloocan City</ion-option>
                      <ion-option value="Las Piñas City" ng-selected="city == 'Las Piñas City'">Las Piñas City</ion-option>
                      <ion-option value="Makati City" ng-selected="city == 'Makati City'">Makati City</ion-option>
                      <ion-option value="Malabon City" ng-selected="city == 'Malabon City'">Malabon City</ion-option>
                      <ion-option value="Mandaluyong City" ng-selected="city == 'Mandaluyong City'">Mandaluyong City</ion-option>
                      <ion-option value="Manila City" ng-selected="city == 'Manila City'">Manila City</ion-option>
                      <ion-option value="Marikina City" ng-selected="city == 'Marikina City'">Marikina City</ion-option>
                      <ion-option value="Muntinlupa City" ng-selected="city == 'Muntinlupa City'">Muntinlupa City</ion-option>
                      <ion-option value="Navotas City" ng-selected="city == 'Navotas City'">Navotas City</ion-option>
                      <ion-option value="Parañaque City" ng-selected="city == 'Parañaque City'">Parañaque City</ion-option>
                      <ion-option value="Pateros City" ng-selected="city == 'Pateros City'">Pateros City</ion-option>
                      <ion-option value="Pasay City" ng-selected="city == 'Pasay City'">Pasay City</ion-option>
                      <ion-option value="Pasig City" ng-selected="city == 'Pasig City'">Pasig City</ion-option>
                      <ion-option value="Quezon City" ng-selected="city == 'Quezon City'">Quezon City</ion-option>
                      <ion-option value="San Juan City" ng-selected="city == 'San Juan City'">San Juan City</ion-option>
                      <ion-option value="Taguig City" ng-selected="city == 'Taguig City'">Taguig City</ion-option>
                      <ion-option value="Valenzuela City" ng-selected="city == 'Valenzuela City'">Valenzuela City</ion-option>
                      <ion-option value="Other" ng-selected="city == 'Other'">Other</ion-option>
                    </ion-select>
                  </ion-item>


                  <!-- Barangay ** IF CITY IS SELECTED -->
                  <ion-item class="form-field" *ngIf="city != 'Other'">
                    <ion-label stacked>Barangay</ion-label>
                    <ion-select  placeholder="Barangay" [(ngModel)]="barangayId" [disabled]="!barangayList" (ionChange)="setBarangay('house')">
                      <ng-container *ngFor="let bl of barangayList let i = index">
                        <ion-option ng-selected="barangay == barangayList[i].name" value="{{i}}">{{barangayList[i].name}}</ion-option>
                      </ng-container>
                    </ion-select>
                    <ion-label error-field no-margin *ngIf="!isBarangayValid"><ion-icon name="ios-alert"></ion-icon> Please select one.</ion-label>
                  </ion-item>
```

**TYPESCRIPT**

```
  getBarangay(property) {
    var city = property == 'house' ? this.city.replace(' City', '') : this.businessCity.replace(' City', '');
    if (property == 'house') {
      this.barangayList = [];
    } else if (property == 'business') {
      this.businessBarangayList = [];
    }

    if ((property == 'house' &&  this.city != 'Other') || (property == 'business' &&  this.businessCity != 'Other')) { 
      let headers = new Headers ({
        'Accept' : 'application/json'
      });
      let options = new RequestOptions({ headers : headers });

      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.http.post(this.apiBaseUrl + city + '/brgy',  options)
        .timeout(10000)
        .toPromise()
        .then((response) =>
        {
          // console.log('Get Barangay List API Response : ', response.json());
          var _response = response.json();
          
          if (property == 'house') {
            for (let element in _response) {  
              this.barangayList.push({  
                name: element.trim(),  
                code: _response[element]
              });
            }
          } else if (property == 'business') {
            for (let element in _response) {  
              this.businessBarangayList.push({  
                name: element,  
                code: _response[element]
              });  
            }
          }
          resolve(response.json());
        })
        .catch((error) =>
        {
          reject(error);
          this.loadingSrvc.hide();
          if (error.name == 'TimeoutError') {
            this.timeOut(property);
          } else {
            this.serverErrorDialog(error);
          }
        });
      });
    }
  }

  setBarangay(property) {
    if (property == 'house') {
      this.barangayCode = this.barangayList[this.barangayId].code;
      this.barangay = this.barangayList[this.barangayId].name;
    } else if (property == 'business') {
      this.businessBarangayCode = this.businessBarangayList[this.businessBarangayId].code;
      this.businessBarangay = this.businessBarangayList[this.businessBarangayId].name;
    }
  }
```

[image: image|280x161]

*Fig 1. There is no displayed/selected option*

[image: image|275x381]

*Fig 2. Displays all the barangay of a selected city*

I hope someone can help me with this. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason behind the `ion-select` not displaying selected option is because of the 2-way data binding on `ion-select`: `[(ngModel)]="barangayId"`

```
<ion-select  placeholder="Barangay" [(ngModel)]="barangayId" [disabled]="!barangayList" (ionChange)="setBarangay('house')">
```

- Because of this 2-way data binding, you are telling angular to show the selected `option` whose `value` property matches the value of `barangayId`
- Currently, you are setting the `option` value as `value="{{i}}"`. Since the `barangayId` does not match any `option` `value`, you can't see any selected option

**Solution:** Either use 2-way data binding with [(ngModel)] and don't add any additional logic like : `ng-selected="barangay == barangayList[i].name"`.

Or

Don't use 2-way dta binding and keep the selected logic in `option` like the following:

```
<ion-option [selected]="barangay == barangayList[i].name" value="{{i}}">
```

You can get the value of `<ion-select>` in `ionChange()` by passing the current value with $event.target.value:

```
 <ion-select  placeholder="Barangay" [disabled]="!barangayList" (ionChange)="setBarangay($event.target.value)">
```

Comment: Thank you bud! It really helped me with my problem :)